Modelling the joint pmf of 2 correlated variables as p(x)*pmf(E(y|x))
Let x,y be 2 correlated counts. We want to model the joint pmf p(x,y). We know that p(x,y) = p(x)p(y|x) = p(y)(x|y). However, what happens when we don't know y|x, but we can estimate E(y|x)? Can't we use p(x)*pmf(E(y|x) in order to model p(x,y)?
Below, I am generating two correlated Poisson variables. Then, I am estimating the expected y given x, E(y|x). After that, I am generating the marginal pmf of x. Finally, I am calculating  p(x)*pmf(E(y|x) to create a matrix, which is meant to represent the joint pmf p(x,y).
I am summing the rows and columns of the pXY matrix, hoping to get back the marginal distributions. This is true for p(x). However, it is not true for p(y), whose variance is clearly higher, suggesting a flow in my logic. Can someone explain what I am doing wrong and how we could get the right joint pmf of (x,y) in this example?
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import norm, poisson

def generate_correlated_poisson(N, mu, rho):
    # Step 1: Generate correlated Gaussian random variables
    mean = [0, 0]  # Mean of the Gaussian variables
    cov = [[1, rho], [rho, 1]]  # Covariance matrix
    
    # Generate N samples from a bivariate normal distribution
    gaussian_samples = np.random.multivariate_normal(mean, cov, N)
    
    # Step 2: Transform Gaussian variables to uniform variables using the CDF
    uniform_samples = norm.cdf(gaussian_samples)
    
    # Step 3: Transform uniform variables to Poisson variables using the inverse CDF (PPF)
    poisson_samples_x = poisson.ppf(uniform_samples[:, 0], mu)
    poisson_samples_y = poisson.ppf(uniform_samples[:, 1], mu)
    
    return poisson_samples_x, poisson_samples_y

# Parameters
N = 100000  # Sample size
mu = 2.5  # Mean of the Poisson distribution
rho = 0.5  # Desired correlation

# Generate correlated Poisson variables
x, y = generate_correlated_poisson(N, mu, rho)

#Estimate E(y|x)
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['y','x'],data=np.vstack((y,x)).T)
ols = smf.ols('y~x',data=df).fit() #could also use smf.poisson('y~np.log(x+1)',data=df).fit()
betas = ols.params.values

#Generate Marginal pmf for X
pX = poisson.pmf(np.arange(0,21),2.5)

#Generate Joint Distribution p(x)*pmf(E(y|x))
pXY = np.array([(pX[i]*poisson.pmf(np.arange(0,21),betas[0]+betas[1]*i)).tolist() for i in range(0,21)])

print(np.sum(pXY,axis=0)) #Marginal pmf p(y) by summing matrix rows
print(np.sum(pXY,axis=1)) #Marginal pmf p(x) by summing matrix columns
print(pX) #True Marginal p(x)
  ```


Could it be that my mistake relates to assuming a Poisson distribution for the pmf of (E(y|x)? i.e. on this line pXY = np.array([(pX[i]*poisson.pmf(np.arange(0,21),betas[0]+betas[1]*i)).tolist() for i in range(0,21)]) this bit poisson.pmf(np.arange(0,21),betas[0]+betas[1]*i) is not true? So, most likely this would be an underdispersed distribution so that the marginal p(y) as derived from the matrix could end up being Poisson? If so, any ideas on whether this could be worked out?
